# How to come up with good titles?

Tags: fiction, romance

Can you help me find a suitable title for my book? I'll tell you the main idea so that you guys can help.

**It is a romance highschool story that revolves around a vampire boy and a human girl. Due to an incident the vampire has to live with the girl. At first their relationship is awkward, but slowly they start becoming friends. Eventually the vampire develops strong feelings for the girl.**

So this is the main idea. And one more thing: they both are faced by rivals who are against their relationship.

So people please let me know how I could choose a suitable title. I have written the whole story a long time ago, but I'm stuck with the title.

Comment: What is the age difference between the boy and the girl?  If it is dramatic, some reference to his taking the "long path" to find his happiness might be appropriate.

Comment: HENRY. according to the story i have written they are both almost 18.

Comment: I find it helpful to find a title only after I have identified at least 5 of components of a story: energy (motivation, spirit, emotion), theme (humane issue), plot, character, scene,   It might help if we had some of that info.  Maybe the question could be redirected to: "Possible Methods for Identifying the Story's Title?"   Sometimes titles kind of come organically, based on those other factors.

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  I've put this question on hold temporarily because brainstorming titles (or other content) doesn't work well for our Q&A format.  If you [edit] it to instead ask *how to come up with* a good title, as opposed to asking for title suggestions, we can reopen it.  Thanks.  You can learn more about how the site works in our short [tour].

Comment: You are still asking for the specific case of coming up with a title for your specific story. The idea was that you changed the question to something like "What is the general process for figuring out a name for a novel that I have written?" so that the answers are also useful for other people who have the same problem, but a different story. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A that aims to provide answers that are applicable to a bigger audience. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: @Secespitus - nice suggested edit - I tweaked the last paragraph to make it more of a "how" than a "what".

Answer (score 4):

How to find a suitable book title:

1. Look at published books in your genre and understand the basic principle behind their titles.
2. Make a list of

   - the theme, topic, premise etc. of your story
   - the setting, atmosphere, main emotions
   - the personalities, weaknesses, drives etc. of your protagonist(s) and antagonist(s)
3. For each of these brainstorm as many words and short phrases as you can come up with.
4. Delete everything that has already been used as a book or movie title.
5. If possible, employ a sample of your target audience and ask them which of the remaining titles would most make them want to read the book.
6. If not, or if your target audience sample suggests several titles, pick the one your gut reaction tells you is the most fitting.
7. Submit your manuscript and be disappointed at the title your publisher chooses.

Comment: Nice summary. Point 7 alone justifies a vote...

Answer (score 1):

"*The Twilight Saga*", nah I'm just kidding.

My (serious) answer:

> Infanguation

It's clearly a pun, referencing the word "infatuation," which is defined as

> an intense but short-lived passion or admiration for someone or something.

Given that your story is about a vampire and love, I'd say "*Infanguation*" comes close to being an appropriate book title. It all depends on the seriousness of the book, though.

If it's an extremely serious novel, this title may not be the best to go with, as opening with a pun may give off the vibe that humor, or at least a not-so-serious tone can be found on the inside.

Comment: well the humor comes when the vampire and girl fight with each other on silly issues at first. after that when they start opening to each other it is serious  .overall it is not totally toooo serious .its a mild temper story. Now if you want i can give you more information but it will be really helpul if u help me find the title. and thanks for the INFANGUATION idea.

Comment: @NoorUl-Ain last night I was going to jokingly suggest *Fangs for nuffin* as your title and decided you wouldn't appreciate it, but as a comment here it seems OK and still makes me chuckle. You could rename your female character Nuffin. I think it would sell. lolol

Comment: @DPT - Made me chuckle, too. Best I had was "I suck at school". But as you and Celtic Tree mention, it all depends on the tone of the book.

Answer (score 0):

The Warming of A Cold Still Heart

or

New Light For a Dark Heart